# How to share locales (chrome and firefox)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I want to develop a browser extension for google chrome and for firefox, which will have shared code.

Is there a way, that both extensions (the firefox version and the chrome version) will use the same localization files?

Currently i have a subfolder "_locales" and a subfolder for each translation, containing a messages.json file. I am accessing the translations via `chrome.i18n.getMessage`.

(How) Can i use these existing translations in my firefox extension?

Comment: look at the new Mozilla Firefox model based on chrome. will soon work outside of beta.

Comment: Localization should be supported the same way in WebExtensions API, which is the new way for firefox addons. Until then you'll have to do localiaiton both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I did it. I think there is no silver bullet for it and (at least) for my case it was not so simple. I am just have all my strings in `.properties` format (because it is more convenient) and I have several build steps that preprocess this files in Chrome's format.